# Binding events to multiple elements in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Is it possible to bind events to multiple elements in HTML without using components.

Ex:

```
<ul>
  <li>
  <li>
  <li>
  <li>
</ul>
```

So can I bind a click events to all those `<li>` elements. If yes, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use event delegation. Since events bubble up, you can put a click handler on the `ul` element and it will fire for a click on any of the contained `li`s. In the `event` object, `target` indicates on which element the event triggered, and `currentTarget`indicates the element the handler is attached to.

```js
new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  methods: {
    something: function(event) {
      console.log('Clicked:', event.target.textContent);
      console.log('Binding is on:', event.currentTarget);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
ul {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
<ul @click="something">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: how to create a functionality for every " li " tag? like: event.target.eventListener(...) ?

Comment: @sina You could put `@click` on each `<li>`. But I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: Is it possible to add EventListener to all elements selected by getElementsByClass() ? My component gets a HTML from a external service and doesnt know markup structure in advance.

Comment: @AviMehenwal For events that bubble, you can put the listener on the element that contains all the elements (body, perhaps) and in the handler check that the element being fired on is one of the set. Or you could iterate the set and put a listener on each item.